# Hide the closest div with a specific ID using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide a closest div with specific ID but its not working for me
Here is what I have tried.

**HTML**

```
<div style="width:50px; height:20px; background-color:green" id="myblock">other content</div>
<div>
    <div style="width:50px; height:100px; background-color:yellow" id="dialog-box">content to hide</div>
    <div> <a href="#" onclick="hideclosest(this);">
        <span> Hide closest Div </span>
    </a>

    </div>
```

**Script**

```
function hideclosest(ctrl) {

    $(ctrl).closest("#dialog-box").hide();
}
```

Here is **Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/c2ewk44o/2/

Comment: `.closest` finds the closest ancestor, not sibling.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to traverse properly. `#dialog-box` is not a `closest` element to that `button`. By the way it is an `id`, so you can select it directly with an id selector. But if you want to select it with some other means use the below code,

```
function hideclosest(ctrl){
   $(ctrl).parent().prev("#dialog-box").hide();
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c2ewk44o/3/)

Answer (score 3):

Id should be unique on a page, therefore:

```
$("#dialog-box").hide();
```

will simply work for you. If you dont have unique id, then you have to convert them into classes or give all the elements unique id

Answer (score -3):

You meant something like:

```js
function hideclosest(ctrl)
{
    $(ctrl).closest("div").prev().hide();
}
```

or like:

```js
function hideclosest(ctrl)
{
    $(ctrl).parent().prev().hide();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

To hide the closet `div` use that code

```
$(ctrl).prev("#dialog-box").hide();
```

Hope solve your problem.

Comment: This traverse is wrong and doesn't explain what closest means